# Glide fails to load image from Resource Id in release version with code obsfucation

Tags: android, android-glide, android-proguard, dexguard

Using Glide, when I try to load from Resid, the **image never loads on my release variant**, it works **fine on debug** variant.
Below is my code.

```
Glide.with(activity.applicationContext).load(R.drawable.mydrawable).into(imageView)
```

However, it works if I give **image URL** or **file path** on both release & debug variant

**Below is my proguard configuration**

```
# Glide
-keep class com.bumptech.glide.** { *;}
-keep public class * implements com.bumptech.glide.module.GlideModule
-keep public class * extends com.bumptech.glide.GeneratedAppGlideModule
-keep public enum com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.bitmap.ImageHeaderParser$** {
  **[] $VALUES;
  public *;
}
```

Comment: no error as such, imageView remains blank

Comment: Try to change `context` for glide.

Comment: it is working with image URL, only resource ID is the issue, it's not related to context, I have tried with activity context as well

Comment: Does it work if you disable shrinking and obfuscation? Are you running ProGuard on your debug builds as well? Could you also specify which version of Glide are you using (e.g. v3 or v4)?

Comment: it works on debug, no code obfuscation, shrinking in debug
using Glide 3.8.0

Answer (score 0):

Could try getting the drawable of the resource first, then loading that with Glide:

`Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.mydrawable, null);
Glide.with(activity.applicationContext).load(d).into(imageView)`

Answer (score 0):

I checked my app apk with [APKStudio](https://github.com/vaibhavpandeyvpz/apkstudio) and found out that some of the raw resources were reduced to zero bytes by ProGuard resource shrinking. To prevent this from happening, I had to create a `keep.xml` file in the `res/raw/` directory as instructed in https://developer.android.com/build/shrink-code#keep-resources and added the following code to `keep.xml` file, which instructs ProGuard to leave the raw resources untouched:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:keep="@raw/**" />
```

Answer (score -2):

What is Glide?

`Glide supports fetching, decoding, and displaying video stills, images, and animated GIFs. Glide includes a flexible API that allows developers to plug in to almost any network stack.`

What you are doing is loading from drawable to imageView.

You don't need Glide for this,you can simply do:

`imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.mydrawable);`

Comment: I want to use Glide for using its inbuilt scaling features.

Comment: You can simply use scaling features of ImageView